# How can I modify an array in my class and get its new output outside of the class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, jsx

```
let arr = []

class Test extends React.Component {
   handleConvertString = (event) => {
    let str = this.inputRef.value;
    let solutions = ['abb','klopp','lopp','hkhk','g','gh','a'] // Returnsolutions()
    if (solutions.includes(str))
    {
        if (arr.includes(str))
        {
            alert("Answer already found");
        }else{
            arr.push(str)
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Please note some code has been left out but the core issue I am having is outlined.

In this piece of code, I need to get the new contents of my arr(array) and return and access it outside my class.
I also need to be able to abstract it to a different file for usage after doing this.

How can I do this?

Comment: Would making arr be a member of your test class and using a getter to read its value be a solution ?

Comment: If I would go about this how would it work? I am sorry I have very limited experience in javascript.

Comment: @AfricanCoder if you want to use arr in other React Components, you can use React Context - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this. Here you can follow the props method to solve your problem.

> You have to pass values as props to other components to access the
>   value of the array outside of this component.

The below example will help you. I have done a few variations in your code to suit myself. The logic will remain the same and you can take help from it.

Note:

- I am using a hardcoded value of str to check the result.
- I am using displayResult variable and map function to just render the
  result. In case the final array has more than one value then map
  function will iterate and append each value of array in displayResult
  variable and render it. You can avoid this as this is only written to show the result.

You can see clearly from the below code how we are passing values to another component (outside). Similarly, if you want to pass the value to another file you have to import that file and pass the value as props to the respective component defined in that file,

```js
let displayResult = "";
function AnotherComponent(props) {
  props.finalArr.map((num, index) => {
     displayResult = displayResult.concat(num)
  });
   return (
   <div>Value of final array is: {displayResult}</div>
    )
 
}


class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {arr: []};
    this.handleConvertString = this.handleConvertString.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleConvertString(event) {
   let str = "abb";
    let solutions = ['abb','klopp','lopp','hkhk','g','gh','a'] 
    if (solutions.includes(str)) {
      let finalArr = this.state.arr;
        if (finalArr.includes(str)) {
            alert("Answer already found");
        }else{
          finalArr.push(str)
            this.setState({arr: finalArr})
        }
    }
    
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" 
            onClick={this.handleConvertString}>
            Click Me
        </button>
        <AnotherComponent finalArr={this.state.arr}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```